# Convert pandas dataframe to custom dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I need to convert to a dictionary in a specific format.  An example of the dataframe data (not real data for ease of presentation) is shown below:

[image]

Here is csv of the input:

```
col1,col2,col3,col3    
abc,1,2,3    
abc,4,5,6    
bcd,10,11,12    
bcd,33,22,11    
cde,3,43,23    
cde,43,23,56
```

The resulting dictionary should be in the following format:

```
{ abc: [[abc, 1, 2, 3], [abc, 4, 5, 6]],  bcd: [[bcd, 10, 11, 12], [bcd, 33, 22, 11]],  cde: [[cde, 3, 43, 23], [cde, 43, 23, 56]] }
```

Is there an efficient (time to process) way to do such conversion?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data or errors. Also, have you tried https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html ?

Comment: Please post text or csv as the input

Comment: @BeChillerToo, yes, I tried all different variations of the dictionary conversion in pandas docs and none seems to give me what I need.

Comment: @balderman I added the sample input as text above, let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like

```py
{k: v.to_numpy() for k, v in df.groupby(df.col1)}
```

does what you want; outputs

```py
>>> {k: v.to_numpy() for k, v in df.groupby(df.col1)}
{'abc': array([['abc', 1, 2, 3],    ['abc', 4, 5, 6]], dtype=object),
 'bcd': array([['bcd', 10, 11, 12], ['bcd', 33, 22, 11]], dtype=object), 
 'cde': array([['cde', 3, 43, 23],  ['cde', 43, 23, 56]], dtype=object)
}
```

This has the advantage of being quite fast, so long as the `numpy ndarray`s are suitable for further use in your case.

Comment: I will need to test if dnarray's are fine for what I use this.  If some of the values in pandas are np.nan, they get recorded in the output as nan.  Is there a way to simply show an empty place instead of nan?  For example, see the first part where output dictionary where no value is assigned after abc: { abc: [[abc, , 2, 3], [abc, 4, 5, 6]],  bcd: [[bcd, 10, 11, 12], [bcd, 33, 22, 11]],  cde: [[cde, 3, 43, 23], [cde, 43, 23, 56]] }

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you'd like to use the empty place for; are you familiar with  [pandas.isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)? I'd expect between those, a solution that meets your needs is feasible.

Comment: I want to replace saving the dataframe to csv (what I've been doing so far) with saving it as dict to save space (I have lots of files to work with).  When I save a dataframe to csv, in the csv cells with "nan" from the dataframe are basically "empty" => this helps reduce the size of such csv files by a factor of x2-3. The dict output you proposed includes "nan" still which will likely impact the ultimate file size to which I will be saving this dictionary.  Hence the question if "nan" can be replaced with empty space/nothing.  Thanks!

Comment: @Vasiliy it sounds like you're using [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to write dataframes to csv; what are you using to write your dictionaries to csv? If you're using Python's [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) module, use `df.fillna(None).groupby(df.col1)` and by default `None` is written to csv as an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
dct = defaultdict(list)
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
  values = list(row.values)
  col1 = values[0]
  dct[col1].append(values)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'abc': [['abc', 1, 2, 3], ['abc', 4, 5, 6]],
             'bcd': [['bcd', 10, 11, 12], ['bcd', 33, 22, 11]],
             'cde': [['cde', 3, 43, 23], ['cde', 43, 23, 56]]})
```

Comment: Thank you, if some of the values in pandas are np.nan, they get recorded in the output dictionary as nan.  Is there a way to simply show an empty place instead of nan?  For example, see the first part of the output dictionary where no value is assigned after abc: { abc: [[abc, , 2, 3], [abc, 4, 5, 6]],  bcd: [[bcd, 10, 11, 12], [bcd, 33, 22, 11]],  cde: [[cde, 3, 43, 23], [cde, 43, 23, 56]] }